# Removing stuck bolts- manual ratchet vs. pneumatic impact ratchet

Tags: wrench, impact-wrench

Which is easier on a stuck bolt, impact wrench or manual ratchet? Or are they about the same?

I had four tiny corner welds on a nut fail removing the below bolt, irritating but not really a problem, just put the nut back with a lockwasher, but it would have been nice to prevent it. I could have hit it with PB Blaster and let it soak, but the failure torque seemed to be very slight.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you run the risk of breaking the bolt in either case, I've had good results using an impact driver when removing such fasteners.

Answer (score 3):

Impact is better.  It vibrates and reverse hammers in between each hammer (weakly).  This helps break up corrosion that may freeze a nut in place.